# have error when execute runner.py (when try to execute Tutorials/TraCI4Traffic Lights)

Tags: python, omnet++, sumo

i want to run this  sumo example 
(Tutorials/TraCI4Traffic Lights)

but when i try to run  python runner.py  i have this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\sumo-win32-0.29.0\sumo-0.29.0\docs\tutorial\traci_tls\runner.py", line 37, in <module>
    from sumolib import checkBinary
  File "C:\sumo-win32-0.29.0\sumo-0.29.0\tools\sumolib\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from . import files, net, output, sensors, shapes
  File "C:\sumo-win32-0.29.0\sumo-0.29.0\tools\sumolib\net\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from . import lane, edge, node, connection, roundabout
  File "C:\sumo-win32-0.29.0\sumo-0.29.0\tools\sumolib\net\lane.py", line 109
    raise ValueError, 'edge for this lane not yet defined'
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

how can solve it??
thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

The error you see is because you run the script with python3, which is probably the default python on your system. SUMO 0.29 did not work well with python3 so either use a more recent SUMO version or start the script with python2 like

```
python2 runner.py
```

Comment: thank for your answer...can i unistall python 3 and install python 2 ??
i can chenge my sumo version because sumo 0.29.0 is compatible with my 0mnet 5.0 and veins 4.5
is it write when i have python 3 enter a code in terminal with python2 ...????

Comment: Yes, probably that is the easiest solution if you do not need python 3 for other programs.